# Правильный запрос к базе. ORM Eloquent. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Есть объект folder в БД у которого существует `id`.

Так же там и другие объекты у которых есть `parent_id` который равен `id` родительского фолдера и так же свои поля `id` `title`.

Как достать все объекты у которых `parent_id` = `id` родителя.

Пробывал так:

```
  public function get($id){

    try{
        $folder = Folder::find($id);
        $folderDataSend = [
          $folder->title, $folder->id, $folder->parent_id
        ];

        $folderList = Folder::where('parent_id', '=', $id )->get();

        return new JsonResponse(['message'=>'Folder has output',$folderDataSend,$folderList ], 200);
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        return  $this->SendError($e);
    }
}
```

Но `$folderList = Folder::where('parent_id', '=', $id )->get()` возвращает только последний найденный элемент.

Нужно получить все объекты.

В идеале получить сразу поля этих объектов: `id`,`title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модели `Folder` добавляете вот это

```
public function scopeMain($query)
{
    return $query->where('parent_id', 0);
}
public function parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Folder::class, 'parent_id');
}
public function subfolders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Folder::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Первое - возможно пригодится. А второе и третье - это как связи между таблицами, только внутри этой же модели.  Т.е. теперь можно

```
$folder = Folder::first(); //или получаете $folder из роута
$subfolders = $folder->subfolders;
$parent = $folder->parent;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! - Всё работает.